# What will be output and explanation?

Tags: java

Below code return boolean false value. Any explanation for this ?

```
String str = "Bee";
String str2 = "Bee";
System.out.println("==" + str == str2);
```

Actual Result : false

Comment: Yes, that's strange. I also don't see why "==Bee" and "Bee" aren't the same String.

Comment: A good place to start here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 0):

`str` and `str2` are both assigned the same `String` instance, since `String` literals are automatically stored in the `String` pool. Therefore `str == str2` is `true`.

However, you are printing the expression `"==" + str == str2`. That expression is evaluated from left to right, so first `"==" + str` is evaluated, and results with the `String` "==Bee". Then the `==` operator is applied to "==Bee" and "Bee", which returns `false`.

If you change the statement to:

```
System.out.println("==" + (str == str2));
```

you'll get `true`, since now the comparison will take place prior to the `String` concatenation.

Comment: In this particular case yes. But using == to compare strings is bad practise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals` to compare string, it will return `true` for this case.

The `==` operator compares that the Strings are exactly the same `Object`.

This *might* theoretically happen in case of internalized strings, but you cannot rely on this. For your case, comparing `String` values, use `str.equals(str2)`.

Comment: Although generally, you are right, that by itself is not the problem here.